# Rest API Data filter from Lookup column by current user and show in dropdown

Tags: sharepoint-online, dropdown, sharepoint-rest-api

I want to show data in lookup column.

from a list which contains lookup column and Username and another list which contains lookup value.

Example: List1 contains Text column value and

List2 contains 2 column First is Lookup column which bind from List1 and another column is person and group which contain username and

List3 contain a lookup column that I want to show only that items which is assign to that user.